# How to enforce column order with Liquibase?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

Setup:

1. liquibase 3.3.5
2. PostgreSQL 9.3
3. Windows 7 Ultimate

Having set the Liquibase.properties file with

```
changeLogFile = C://temp/changeset.xml,
```

I created a diff file with Liquibase (3.3.5).

```
liquibase.bat diffChangeLog
```

Examination of the changeset.xml file shows

```
-<addColumn tableName="view_dx">
         <column type="int8" name="counter" defaultValueNumeric="0" defaultValue="0"/>
</addColumn
```

Problem is when

```
 liquibase.bat update
```

is run, the changed table is NOT in the same column order as the reference table. This causes issues with the stored procedures using SETOF to return table rows.

Without destroying the existing table on the target database, how can column order be enforced using Liquibase?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can, in general, get Liquibase to enforce a column ordering. You will probably need to change your stored procedures to use column names rather than relying on position, which is a good habit to get into anyway.

Comment: Agreed...unfortunately I am using stored procedures to feed back into an entityframework that seems to require the "SETOF" notation, so the column ordering is critical.  Ideas?

Comment: I think the only recourse you have at this point is to start looking at the Liquibase source code and see if you can write a test that expresses your requirement. If you can modify the Liquibase source itself to do what you want, you can probably get that merged in. You may also be able to write a Liquibase extension that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `afterColumn` attribute of `addColumn` tag ?